# Nswag adds the path of the generated file at the end of the generated file

Tags: c#, reactjs, swagger, web-parts, nswag

I am running into a strange issue with my Nswag generated file. After running the scrip for generating the code it is doing it successfully, but at the end of the file it is adding the path of the file itself.

I have already tried to:

- Delete the node_modules folder and re-run `npm install`
- Delete the package-lock.json file and re-run `npm install`
- Re-run `npm install`
- Found a single person having this issue who posted an issue in GitHub: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/3172
- Search the deep dark 3th page of Google

#### After script execution

That is what I get after I generate the file

```
function throwException(message: string, status: number, response: string, headers: { [key: string]: any; }, result?: any): any {
  throw new SwaggerException(message, status, response, headers, result);
}

C:\Users\USER_NAME\source\repos\SOLUTION_NAME\src\backend\api-client-extentions.ts
```

Any help is appreciated!

### Setup:

#### Backend:

I have a C# project running as my backend providing all of the needed controllers that have to be translated with the Nswag

#### Frontend

I have a Microsoft SharePoint Online WebPart solution wrapped in a React framework.

### Config files

#### config.api.nswag

```
{
  "runtime": "Default",
  "defaultVariables": null,
  "documentGenerator": {
    "fromDocument": {
      "url": "https://localhost:8081/swagger/BACKEND_PATH/swagger.json",
      "output": null,
      "newLineBehavior": "Auto"
    }
  },
  "codeGenerators": {
    "openApiToTypeScriptClient": {
      "className": "ApiClient",
      "moduleName": "",
      "namespace": "",
      "typeScriptVersion": 2.7,
      "template": "Fetch",
      "promiseType": "Promise",
      "httpClass": "HttpClient",
      "withCredentials": false,
      "useSingletonProvider": false,
      "injectionTokenType": "OpaqueToken",
      "rxJsVersion": 6.0,
      "dateTimeType": "Date",
      "nullValue": "Undefined",
      "generateClientClasses": true,
      "generateClientInterfaces": false,
      "generateOptionalParameters": false,
      "exportTypes": true,
      "wrapDtoExceptions": true,
      "exceptionClass": "SwaggerException",
      "clientBaseClass": "ApiClientBase",
      "wrapResponses": false,
      "wrapResponseMethods": [],
      "generateResponseClasses": true,
      "responseClass": "SwaggerResponse",
      "protectedMethods": [],
      "configurationClass": null,
      "useTransformOptionsMethod": true,
      "useTransformResultMethod": false,
      "generateDtoTypes": true,
      "operationGenerationMode": "SingleClientFromOperationId",
      "markOptionalProperties": true,
      "generateCloneMethod": false,
      "typeStyle": "Interface",
      "enumStyle": "Enum",
      "useLeafType": false,
      "classTypes": [],
      "extendedClasses": [],
      "extensionCode": "src/backend/api-client-extentions.ts",
      "generateDefaultValues": true,
      "excludedTypeNames": [],
      "excludedParameterNames": [],
      "handleReferences": false,
      "generateConstructorInterface": true,
      "convertConstructorInterfaceData": false,
      "importRequiredTypes": true,
      "useGetBaseUrlMethod": false,
      "baseUrlTokenName": "API_BASE_URL",
      "queryNullValue": "",
      "inlineNamedDictionaries": false,
      "inlineNamedAny": false,
      "templateDirectory": null,
      "typeNameGeneratorType": null,
      "propertyNameGeneratorType": null,
      "enumNameGeneratorType": null,
      "serviceHost": null,
      "serviceSchemes": null,
      "output": "src/backend/api-client-generated.ts",
      "newLineBehavior": "Auto"
    },    
  }
}
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-new-solution",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test",
    "generate:nswag:api": "nswag run config.api.nswag"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "7.174.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.14.0",
    "nswag": "13.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "16.9.51",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.8",
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-tslint-rules": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.9": "0.4.47",
    "gulp": "~4.0.2",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.33"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. As the github issue suggests, it only happens when using the extensionCode property. From our testing we worked out that this happens if nswag can't locate the extension code file *relative* to where the command is run from.

You should be able to use a relative path to make it work, if your `package.json` is at the top level for example that may be as simple as changing the extensionCode property to:

```json
"extensionCode": "./src/backend/api-client-extentions.ts",
```

We chose to put our extension code file in the same location as our generated client and added a powershell script to call nswag from the same location i.e. in `config.api.nswag`:

```json
"extensionCode": "api-client-extentions.ts",
...
"output": "api-client-generated.ts",
```

and in `src/backend` we would have a generate.ps1:

```
Set-Location -Path $PSScriptRoot

& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Rico Suter\NSwagStudio\Win\nswag.exe" run config.api.nswag
```

which can be run on the fly from VS Code whenever we want to regenerate the client.